# Longtable does not work

Tags: longtable, landscape

I have problems in splitting one table in 2 using landscape mode: I tried to generate it from tablesgeneraton to have it correct, but the longtable command does not work, and the table exit from one page in landascape mode.
No errors from the server give me any hint.

I would like to split it into two, horizontal pages.

Here the full code (hopefully a correct MWE - I cannot add the document class since it is a tailored one, but `article`, or `book` give me the same outcome):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
    \begin{longtable}{lllllllllll}
        \caption{} \\
        \label{tab:my-table}\\
        \toprule
        Reference               & Seed generation & Production method       & Seed addition   & Crystallization unit     &                                                                 Dimensions                                                      & Flow pattern                                                     & Material and dispersant & Size size control                                                  & Yield estimation                                                                                & Solid loading     \\ \midrule                                                          
        Present work            & Off-line                                                           & Batch + filtration                                                           & Continuous      & Tubular microreactor                                                                         & 1 mm ID, 60 cm L                                                                                                             & Two-phase \newline bubble flow & PCM in water                                                               & CSD, sieving, \newline filtering & Yes                                                                                             & 2\%, 0.8\% wt                                                          \\
        \cite{Eder2010}         & Off-line                                                           & Batch in solution                                                            & Continuous      & Tubular reactor                                                                              & 2 mm ID, 15 m L                                                                                                              & Single-phase                                                     & ASA in ethanol                                                             & CSD                                                                & 569\% \newline mean mass flow/total seed flow       & 5\%wt                                                                 \\
        \cite{Eder2011}         & Off-line                                                           & Batch in solution                                                            & Continuous      & Tubular reactor                                                                              & 2 mm ID, 15 m L                                                                                                              & Single-phase                                                     & ASA in ethanol                                                             & CSD                                                                & 779-407-348\% \newline mean mass flow/total seed flow & 7, 14, 16\% wt                                                         \\
        \cite{Eder2012}         & In-line                                                            & US-aided nucleation           & Continuous      & Tubular reactor                                                                              & 2 mm ID, 27 m L                                                                                                              & Two-phase slug flow   & ASA in ethanol                                                             & CSD                                                                & 172-700\% mean mass flow/ \newline total seed flow   & Based on relative flow rate \\
        \cite{Jiang2014}        & In-line                                                            & Micromixing (cooling)            & Continuous      & Tubular reactor                                                                              & 3.1 mm ID, 15.2 m L                                                                                                          & Two-phase slug flow & LAM in water                                                               & No                                                                 & 87\% product solid/total solid                       & /                                                                      \\
        \cite{Jiang2015}        & In-line                                                            & US-aided nucleation              & Continuous      & Tubular reactor                                                                              & 3.1 mm ID, 15.2 m L                                                                                                          & Two-phase slug flow   & LAM in water                                                               & No                                                                 & 74\% product solid/ total solid                      & /                                                                      \\
        \cite{Jordens2017}      & In-line                                                            & US-aided nucleation and growth    & Semi-continuous & Tubular nucleation + \newline batch growth         & 5 mm ID, 7 m L tubular nucleation \newline 53x83x97 mm batch vessel                & Single-phase                                                     & PCM in water                                                               & No                                                                 & No                                                                                              & /                                                                      \\
        \cite{Wong2013}         & In-line                                                            & Single crystal contact nucleation & Continuous      & Nucleator +  \newline tubular reactor           & 3.2 mm ID \newline 20 ft L                                                        & Single-phase                                                     & Glycine/PCM in water            & CSD                                                                & No                                                                                              & Single crystal                                                         \\
        \cite{MendezDelRio2006} & In-line                                                            & Cooling                                                                      & Continuous      & Tubular nucleation (LFTC) + \newline batch growth & 1.6 mm ID, 7.62 m L LFTC \newline 500 ml batch vessel                            & Single-phase                                                     & PCM in ethanol/methanol        & No                                                                 & No                                                                                              & /                                                                      \\
        \cite{Fatemi2021}       & In-line                                                            & Cooling                                                                      & Continuous      & Tubular microreactor + \newline tubular growth     & 1 mm ID, 60 cm L tubular nucleation \newline 2 mm ID, 1.4, 4, 8 m L tubular growth & Two-phase  bubble flow & PCM in water                                                               & No                                                                 & 2-70\% measured/ \newline maximum concentration    & /                                                                      \\ \bottomrule
    \end{longtable}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Could you please help me see where I am doing it wrong? Thank you!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Please prepare a complete and self-contained [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the output you get. Waht exactly does "does not work" mean? Do you get an error message? If so, which one? Or do you just get an output that is different from the expected? If so, how does your output look like and what would you like to change about it?

Comment: your error will be in code you have not shown, so it is hard to help.  the `\label` should be in the  \caption command not on a line of its own but that will just make bad output, nit an error.

Comment: Hello everyone! I am going to edit the code so that I can make it clearer. I apologise, this is my first post. @leandriis

Comment: Hello everyone! I am going to edit the code so that I can make it clearer. I apologise, this is my first post. @DavidCarlisle

Comment: your table only has 10  rows so does not have a page break, but it is too wide to fit even on a landscape page, you need to format your data in a more reasonable way, even if the fonts and table were adjusted it will be hard for anyone to read a table this wide.

Comment: How to make sure a table fits into the available space depends a lot on how much space there is. The size of the textblock is mostly determined by the documentclass you use. So without this information, others can only provide general hints, such as using `xltabular` instead of `longtable`. (Something like `\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{lXXXXXXXXXX}` could get you started. Depending on the size of the textblock this might lead to overlaps or too narrow columns.) Other approaches can be found here: [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/134144)

Comment: In order to save some space, you could merge the two columns "Seed generation"  and "seed addition" into a single column. You could also remove lengthier text from the "Yield estimation"  column (such as "mean mass flow/total seed flow") and use table notes to show this information below the table.

Answer (score 1):

It fits (but is still not very readable) if you adjust the column widths:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

% not needed as you hav epdflscape\usepackage{lscape}
% not needed here \usepackage{rotating}
% almost never needed in current latex \usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array,multirow,graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\small
\setlength\LTleft{-3cm}
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
    \begin{longtable}{@{}
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{1.5cm}
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2cm}
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2cm}
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2cm}
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2cm}
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2cm}
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2cm}
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2cm}
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{1.5cm}% size and control
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2cm}
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{1.5cm}% solid loading
@{}}
        \caption{} \\
        \label{tab:my-table}\\
        \toprule
        Reference               & Seed generation & Production method       & Seed addition   & Crystall\-iz\-ation unit     &                                                                 Dimensions                                                      & Flow pattern                                                     & Material and dispersant & Size size control                                                  & Yield estimation                                                                                & Solid loading     \\ \midrule                                                          
        Present work            & Off-line                                                           & Batch + filtration                                                           & Continuous      & Tubular microreactor                                                                         & 1 mm ID, 60 cm L                                                                                                             & Two-phase \newline bubble flow & PCM in water                                                               & CSD, sieving, \newline filtering & Yes                                                                                             & 2\%, 0.8\% wt                                                          \\
        \cite{Eder2010}         & Off-line                                                           & Batch in solution                                                            & Continuous      & Tubular reactor                                                                              & 2 mm ID, 15 m L                                                                                                              & Single-phase                                                     & ASA in ethanol                                                             & CSD                                                                & 569\% \newline mean mass flow/total seed flow       & 5\%wt                                                                 \\
        \cite{Eder2011}         & Off-line                                                           & Batch in solution                                                            & Continuous      & Tubular reactor                                                                              & 2 mm ID, 15 m L                                                                                                              & Single-phase                                                     & ASA in ethanol                                                             & CSD                                                                & 779-407-348\% \newline mean mass flow/total seed flow & 7, 14, 16\% wt                                                         \\
        \cite{Eder2012}         & In-line                                                            & US-aided nucleation           & Continuous      & Tubular reactor                                                                              & 2 mm ID, 27 m L                                                                                                              & Two-phase slug flow   & ASA in ethanol                                                             & CSD                                                                & 172-700\% mean mass flow/ \newline total seed flow   & Based on relative flow rate \\
        \cite{Jiang2014}        & In-line                                                            & Micromixing (cooling)            & Continuous      & Tubular reactor                                                                              & 3.1 mm ID, 15.2 m L                                                                                                          & Two-phase slug flow & LAM in water                                                               & No                                                                 & 87\% product solid/total solid                       & /                                                                      \\
        \cite{Jiang2015}        & In-line                                                            & US-aided nucleation              & Continuous      & Tubular reactor                                                                              & 3.1 mm ID, 15.2 m L                                                                                                          & Two-phase slug flow   & LAM in water                                                               & No                                                                 & 74\% product solid/ total solid                      & /                                                                      \\
        \cite{Jordens2017}      & In-line                                                            & US-aided nucleation and growth    & Semi-continuous & Tubular nucleation + \newline batch growth         & 5 mm ID, 7 m L tubular nucleation \newline 53x83x97 mm batch vessel                & Single-phase                                                     & PCM in water                                                               & No                                                                 & No                                                                                              & /                                                                      \\
        \cite{Wong2013}         & In-line                                                            & Single crystal contact nucleation & Continuous      & Nucleator +  \newline tubular reactor           & 3.2 mm ID \newline 20 ft L                                                        & Single-phase                                                     & Glycine/PCM in water            & CSD                                                                & No                                                                                              & Single crystal                                                         \\
        \cite{MendezDelRio2006} & In-line                                                            & Cooling                                                                      & Continuous      & Tubular nucleation (LFTC) + \newline batch growth & 1.6 mm ID, 7.62 m L LFTC \newline 500 ml batch vessel                            & Single-phase                                                     & PCM in ethanol/methanol        & No                                                                 & No                                                                                              & /                                                                      \\
        \cite{Fatemi2021}       & In-line                                                            & Cooling                                                                      & Continuous      & Tubular microreactor + \newline tubular growth     & 1 mm ID, 60 cm L tubular nucleation \newline 2 mm ID, 1.4, 4, 8 m L tubular growth & Two-phase  bubble flow & PCM in water                                                               & No                                                                 & 2-70\% measured/ \newline maximum concentration    & /                                                                      \\ \bottomrule
    \end{longtable}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [my previous suggestions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/598135/longtable-does-not-work#comment1499773_598135) and with the help of `xltabular` and `threeparttablex`, as well as a smaller font size nd a slightly decreased value of `\tabcolsep`, you can get the following output:

[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\hspace{0pt}\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}


\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\begin{ThreePartTable}
\begin{TableNotes}
\item[a] mean mass flow/total seed flow
\item[b] product solid/ total solid 
\item[c] measured/  maximum concentration                     
\end{TableNotes}
    \begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{l*{10}{L}}
        \caption{}
        \label{tab:my-table}\\
        \toprule
        Reference               & Seed generation \& addition & Production method       & Crystallization unit     &                                                                 Dimensions                                                      & Flow pattern                                                     & Material and dispersant & Size size control                                                  & Yield estimation                                                                                & Solid loading     \\ \midrule
\endfirsthead
        \caption[]{ - continued from previous page}\\
        \toprule
        Reference               & Seed generation \& addition & Production method       & Crystallization unit     &                                                                 Dimensions                                                      & Flow pattern                                                     & Material and dispersant & Size size control                                                  & Yield estimation                                                                                & Solid loading     \\ \midrule
\endhead      
\bottomrule
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\insertTableNotes
\endlastfoot                                           
        Present work            & Off-line, Continuous                                                          & Batch + filtration                                                                 & Tubular microreactor                                                                         & 1 mm ID, 60 cm L                                                                                                             & Two-phase bubble flow & PCM in water                                                               & CSD, sieving,  filtering & Yes                                                                                             & 2\%, 0.8\% wt                                                          \\ \addlinespace
        
        \cite{Eder2010}         & Off-line, Continuous                                                           & Batch in solution                                                                  & Tubular reactor                                                                              & 2 mm ID, 15 m L                                                                                                              & Single-phase                                                     & ASA in ethanol                                                             & CSD                                                                & 569\%\tnote{a}      & 5\%wt                                                                 \\ \addlinespace
        
        \cite{Eder2011}         & Off-line, Continuous                                                          & Batch in solution                                                                  & Tubular reactor                                                                              & 2 mm ID, 15 m L                                                                                                              & Single-phase                                                     & ASA in ethanol                                                             & CSD                                                                & 779-407-348\%\tnote{a} & 7, 14, 16\% wt                                                         \\ \addlinespace
        
        \cite{Eder2012}         & In-line, Continuous                                                            & US-aided nucleation                 & Tubular reactor                                                                              & 2 mm ID, 27 m L                                                                                                              & Two-phase slug flow   & ASA in ethanol                                                             & CSD                                                                & 172-700\% \tnote{a}  & Based on relative flow rate \\ \addlinespace
        
        \cite{Jiang2014}        & In-line, Continuous                                                             & Micromixing (cooling)                 & Tubular reactor                                                                              & 3.1 mm ID, 15.2 m L                                                                                                          & Two-phase slug flow & LAM in water                                                               & No                                                                 & 87\%\tnote{b} & /                                                                      \\ \addlinespace
        
        \cite{Jiang2015}        & In-line, Continuous                                                            & US-aided nucleation                    & Tubular reactor                                                                              & 3.1 mm ID, 15.2 m L                                                                                                          & Two-phase slug flow   & LAM in water                                                               & No                                                                 & 74\%\tnote{b}  & /                                                                      \\ \addlinespace
        
        
        \cite{Jordens2017}      & In-line, Semi-continuous                                                            & US-aided nucleation and growth     & Tubular nucleation +  batch growth         & 5 mm ID, 7 m L tubular nucleation  53x83x97 mm batch vessel                & Single-phase                                                     & PCM in water                                                               & No                                                                 & No                                                                                              & /                                                                      \\ \addlinespace
        
        \cite{Wong2013}         & In-line, Continuous                                                           & Single crystal contact nucleation       & Nucleator +   tubular reactor           & 3.2 mm ID  20 ft L                                                        & Single-phase                                                     & Glycine/ PCM in water            & CSD                                                                & No                                                                                              & Single crystal                                                         \\ \addlinespace
        
        \cite{MendezDelRio2006} & In-line, Continuous                                                             & Cooling                                                                           & Tubular nucleation (LFTC) +  batch growth & 1.6 mm ID, 7.62 m L LFTC  500 ml batch vessel                            & Single-phase                                                     & PCM in ethanol/ methanol        & No                                                                 & No                                                                                              & /                                                                      \\ \addlinespace
        
        \cite{Fatemi2021}       & In-line, Continuous                                                           & Cooling                                                                            & Tubular microreactor +  tubular growth     & 1 mm ID, 60 cm L tubular nucleation  2 mm ID, 1.4, 4, 8 m L tubular growth & Two-phase  bubble flow & PCM in water                                                               & No                                                                 & 2-70\% \tnote{c}     & /                                                                      \\ 
    \end{xltabular}
    \end{ThreePartTable}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @DavidCarlisle indeed, my initial idea was to split the columns of the table and not the rows, thanks for the tips!

Comment: thank you very much @leandriis ! This is great